# Can a new cassandra node be created by copying sstables directly to a new machine?

Tags: cassandra

We had three nodes in our cluster with replication factor of three. Lost one because of disk issues. The backed up files from this node are also corrupted.

I am looking at these options:

1. Join a fresh node to the existing two nodes and let it catch up. This would be very slow as there is about 1TB data.
2. Copy all sstable data from another node to a new node and add it as the third node. Since each node has all the data the hope is this should be superfast.

Will option two work, or will this cause other issues? Are there any other options?

We are running Cassandra version 1.1.10.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used 1.1, but option 2 should work. Make sure to use the same `initial_token` config value for the new host (although it shouldn't really matter with your topology). Running a repair afterwards is recommended.